# RTF font between two sections

Tags: rtf

Can someone please help me with this RTF. Sorry about this lengthy RTF string.
Why is the font different in both sections.

"Test content" is in Calibri 10 whereas "purpose content" is in Times New Roman 10

Can someone point me to what is it in the RTF that causes this change?

Thank you very much

```html
{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Calibri;}{\f1 Times New Roman;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;}{\*\defchp \fs22}{\stylesheet {\ql\fs22 Normal;}{\*\cs1\fs22 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*\cs2\sbasedon1\fs22 Line Number;}{\*\cs3\ul\fs22\cf1 Hyperlink;}{\*\ts4\tsrowd\fs22\ql\trautofit1\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Normal Table;}{\*\ts5\tsrowd\sbasedon4\fs22\ql\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10\trautofit1\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Table Simple 1;}}{\*\listoverridetable}\nouicompat\splytwnine\htmautsp\sectd\marglsxn1440\margrsxn1440\margtsxn1440\margbsxn1440\trowd\irow0\irowband0\lastrow\trgaph108\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trleft-108\trftsWidth1\trautofit1\trpaddfl3\trpaddl108\trpaddfr3\trpaddr108\tblindtype3\tblind0\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth9576\clpadfr3\clpadr108\clpadft3\clpadt108\cellx9495\pard\plain\ql\intbl{\b\fs22\cf0 BACKGROUND AND MANAGEMENT ANALYSIS}\b\fs22\par\pard\plain\ql\intbl{\b\fs22\cf0 BRANCH NAME}\b\fs22\cell\trowd\irow0\irowband0\lastrow\trgaph108\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trleft-108\trftsWidth1\trautofit1\trpaddfl3\trpaddl108\trpaddfr3\trpaddr108\tblindtype3\tblind0\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth9576\clpadfr3\clpadr108\clpadft3\clpadt108\cellx9495\row\pard\plain\ql\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql{\lang1033\langfe1033\fs20\cf0 Test   content}\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql\fs22\par\pard\plain\ql{\fs22\cf0 \line }\fs22\par\trowd\irow0\irowband0\lastrow\trgaph108\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trleft-108\trftsWidth1\trpaddfl3\trpaddl108\trpaddfr3\trpaddr108\tblindtype3\tblind0\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth9537\clpadfr3\clpadr108\clpadft3\clpadt108\cellx9450\pard\plain\ql\intbl{\b\fs20\cf0 PURPOSE}\b\fs20\cell\trowd\irow0\irowband0\lastrow\trgaph108\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trleft-108\trftsWidth1\trpaddfl3\trpaddl108\trpaddfr3\trpaddr108\tblindtype3\tblind0\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth9537\clpadfr3\clpadr108\clpadft3\clpadt108\cellx9450\row\pard\plain\ql\fs22\par\pard\plain\ql{\lang1033\langfe1033\f1\fs20\cf0 purpose content}\f1\fs20\par\pard\plain\ql\fs22\par\pard\plain\ql\fs22\par}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text "purpose content" is preceded by \f1, which is changing the font to Times New Roman.

To explain how this works in a nutshell, all RTF files define a font table (\fonttbl), which is a list of fonts. Each font is assigned a font index. One font in the font table is picked as the default by using \deffontN, where N is the font index. Throughout the document, the current font is changed by specifying \fN, where N is the font index. The \plain control changes the current font back to the default.

If you want to go deeper and learn more about RTF, you can read the specification. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725. For a more accessible introduction, see https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch01.html

Comment: Yes thank you people were not answering here. It made me dig into that document/link you pointed out.. Thank you very much